# Ajuda com inner join: "No space left on device"

Tags: memória, join, inner, pgadmin

Não tenho muitos conhecimentos em programação e experiência em SQL, no entanto, preciso fazer uma busca em um banco de dados PostrgeeSQL (estou usando pgAdminIII) onde preciso unir duas tabelas.

```
create table table_new as 
select table.x1, table.x2, table.x3, table.x4, table2.x1, table2.x5, table2.x6, table2.x1 as teste
from table inner join table2 on table.x1 = table2.x1
```

Porém, com essa busca acabo recendo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> ERROR: could not extend file "base/17675/43101.15": No space left on device
>   SQL state: 53100
>   Hint: Check free disk space.

Alguém poderia me dar uma dica de como otimizar a minha busca de forma que eu consiga unir as duas tabelas que eu preciso??

Comment: Já experimentou liberar espaço de armazenagem/disco, conforme a mensagem de erro? Ou usar um where para filtrar somente os dados desejados, quem sabe.

Answer (score 1):

Parece que o problema não está relacionado com o postgresql. O computador está sem espaço livre, só isso: "*No space left on device*"